# Makefile - single colon in recipe body

Tags: makefile

I've got the following recipe:

```
.PHONY: all
all: this that
  @ :
```

I believe the @ in the last line prevents the colon from being printed out, but what does the colon do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single colon is the shell's "do nothing" operator.  So, it does nothing.  See the docs for the shell.

Comment: execuse me, so why people put single colon after @ if that line does nothing?

Comment: Some people think the `@` (which implies an empty string sent to the shell) looks weird.

Comment: More specifically, the doc says 'Do nothing *beyond expanding ARGUMENTS* and performing redirections'. So the behavior depends on the ARGUMENTS which *may have redirections* where we may do somthing. But here ARGUMENTS is none so we do nothing.